# Best practice for pagination big table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination, query-optimization

I have a pretty big table ~100m rows:

```
create table transfer
(
    id                  bigint                   not null primary key,
    db_updated_at       timestamp with time zone,
    ...
);
```

I need to iterate it ordering by db_updated_at desc, id desc.
There's application with REST api, which generates query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM transfer
WHERE "db_updated_at" < '2022-11-18 23:38:44+03' OR (db_updated_at = '2022-11-18 23:38:44+03' and id < 154998555017734)
ORDER BY "db_updated_at" DESC, "id" DESC LIMIT 100
```

But it's extremly slow ( in explain I see this:

```
Limit  (cost=0.56..26.92 rows=10 width=230) (actual time=182494.092..182494.273 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using transfer_db_updated_at_id_desc on transfer  (cost=0.56..55717286.28 rows=21142503 width=230) (actual time=182494.089..182494.266 rows=10 loops=1)
        Filter: ((db_updated_at < '2022-11-18 20:38:44+00'::timestamp with time zone) OR ((db_updated_at = '2022-11-18 20:38:44+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (id < '154998555017734'::bigint)))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 16040385
Planning Time: 0.364 ms
Execution Time: 182494.312 ms
```

What it the best practice to iterate table with 2 field ordering? I can't iterate only by id because I need s specific timeframe

Comment: [use-the-index-luke.com](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it as a tuple comparison rather a complex comparison of multiple scalars:

```
SELECT * FROM transfer
WHERE (db_updated_at,id) < ('2022-11-18 23:38:44+03',154998555017734)
ORDER BY "db_updated_at" DESC, "id" DESC LIMIT 100;
```